# get text from a jcombobox as you type

Tags: java, mysql

At the moment i have a work around for this problem it is to use a textfield and a combobox this however is very untidy and wish to remove the textfield as this is to enter data into a mysql database and also retrieve it so i need to be able to add the result to the combobox as thou it where a textfield

```
 private void jTextField15KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
     String ThePub = jTextField15.getText();
      int publengh = ThePub.length();
       if (publengh > 2) {
         jTextField15.setVisible(false);
         fillpub(ThePub);
                       }  
  public void fillpub(String pub) {
    Connection con;
     ResultSet rs;
     PreparedStatement pst;
     String thedata;
     try {
         String cs = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/booksalvation4";
         String user = "root";
         String password = "letmein";
         pub = "'" + pub + "%'";
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(cs, user, password);
           String query = "select * from publisher where name like" + pub;
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                 rs = pst.executeQuery();
         while (rs.next()) {
               thedata = rs.getString(2);
             jComboBox11.addItem(thedata);
         }
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(mainJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
  }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a KeyListener.

Instead you should be using a `DocumentListener`. You can add the DocumentListener to the Document of the text field that is being used as the editor for the JComboBox.

See the `getEditor()` method of JComboBox. Once you have the `ComboBoxEditor` you can get the editor component which by default is a JTextField. Then you add the DocumentListener to the text field.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information.